# How to add file to a project and reference it?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, file, csv

I'm really new to iOS development, so this question might be silly, but I didn't find an answer for it.

I have a project in swift for iOS device and I want to include a csv file in my project and then use it in code, how can I add this file to the project and then use it in viewController class?

this is my project structure (yes, it's very simple)

[image: project structure]

and this is what i'm trying to do in code, but it doesn't work.

[image: in code]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a resource file to project by just drag and dropping. When you do so, a popup will appear, you need to select your target in it for linking it with your current target.

In your above code there is a mistake. You only need to specify the filename without extension in `pathForResource:` method.

Instead of:

```
let file = "europe_dancing.csv"
```

You only need to specify:

```
let file = "europe_dancing"
```